# What is the meaning of 'from someone on down'?

Tags: meaning

I was reading about the recent news in Houston and encountered the following sentence.

> Everybody at that event had a responsibility, from the artist on down.

I guess it means everyone is responsible for what happened starting from the artist. But I couldn't confirm my understanding. Can you give some examples or further explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It implies that the artist was the most important person at the event, and 'from him/her on down' is the hierarchy of people present down to the [supposedly] least important.

Comment: Absolutely, Kate. Other examples would be "Everyone in the government must take responsibility for this from the President on down" and "The staff, from the manager on  down, welcome you to our restaurant." In Britain though, it's a little more common to omit the 'on' giving "... from the Prime Minister down" for example.